# Unexpected behavior of "base-href" with a angular routing app

Tags: angular

For running an angular app on a sub path there is the compiler option `base-href`.

But it doesn't work with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) as expected. It results in an double sub path or inexplicable redirect.

Simple steps to reproduce are as follows:

1. Create new routing app on command line (angular 14) by `ng new myapp` – **routing IS NEEDED** – and enter directory `myapp/`.
2. Remove the unused files `app.component.html` and `app.component.css`.
3. Replace the content of your `app.component.ts` by the following dummy content:

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core'

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       template: `<img src="favicon.ico" alt="icon" />`
   })
   export class AppComponent {

       constructor() { // @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) readonly unnecessary: string
       }
   }
   ```
4. Install `http-server` by `npm i http-server -D`.
5. Make a build by `ng build --base-href myapp`.
6. Start the app by http-server: `./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/` and enter `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`. The app redirects to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/myapp/`. I have a double sub path. Without routing module this doesn't happen.

[image]

7. Finally I found out that the usage of the `APP_BASE_HREF` DI token avoids this redirect. Leading `/` of `/myapp` is necessary.

   ```
   ...
   @NgModule({
       ...
       providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/myapp' }],
       ...
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```

Could anyone explain this behavior and what the compiler-option `--base-href` and the DI token `APP_BASE_HREF` does?

---

used `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I am afraid not.